# Get all branches(root to leaf) of a binary tree as lists in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree, traversal

I've made a binary tree in Python in the form of a dictionary, in which every entry is of the form `key: value`. For example,

```
btree = {..., 
         node1: [value, nodeNoOfLeftChild, nodeNoOfRightChild],
         ... }
```

All nodes have the entries in the same format but some nodes can be missing too.

For example, if node number 5 has value X and child node numbers are 12 and 13, the entry looks like.

`tree[5] = [X, 12, 13]`

But it's possible that node 13 doesn't exist so node 5 only has one child.
It is also possible that node 12 & 13 both do not exist, which makes node 5 a leaf node.

I want to get all the branches (root to leaf) of the tree as lists but the problem is the list length is variable depending upon the branching.

How do I make a function that takes in this dictionary and gives out lists?

Comment: You're only given examples for 3 nodes. What if there are more than 2 levels? You might also want to look at pre-order traversal for BSTs.

Comment: I've given example for how I've stored every node of the tree.

Comment: There will be similar entries for child nodes, and their children and so on

Comment: Given node 5 does not have any child nodes, then does it's list in the binary tree really have other entries than it's value?

Comment: In what format do you want the braches to be returned?

Comment: What do you mean "possible that node 13 does not exist"?  How do you know if node 13 exists or not?  Do you have to look in the map to see?  Why would it not be the case that if there's a number in one of the child slots, that means the child exists?  Why not just have a sentinel value, like None or -1 to represent the absence of child nodes.

Comment: Once you can clearly define the structure of your tree, it would be a matter of writing a recursive function that traverses your tree and keeps track of each node that it has traversed to get to a given point.  Then, when your traversal reaches a leaf node, you can come up with the complete list of branches to that leaf, record it in an outer list (you'll be creating a list of lists), and move on with the traversal.

Comment: @JugalMChoksi but you haven't given the expected output for a BST that has more than 3 nodes. How exactly do you want to represent it in a list?

Comment: One does not usually use a map to create a binary tree.  Rather, you use a fixed structure, usually a Node class, to do this.  You could use a simple array like you're showing, but there's no reason to put the nodes in a map.  Instead, your child entries should just be references to other nodes, or None if there is no child node in a particular slot. - what you're talking about will work though.  You just have to define well how to interpret what values could be in the arrays in the map.

Comment: @MaxPowers Node 5 itself can be a child node

Comment: @MaxPower Each branch returned as a list

Comment: @Steve I am first writing the value and numbers if child nodes in the dictionary and then calling the nodes recursively. In some me conditions one or both child may not exist. We can check if it exists by: if tree.get('13') == None

Comment: @absolutelydevastated By list I meant multiple lists and not just one. One list containing value/node numbers of all present in branch from root to leaf

Comment: Yes, if you have to have numbers in there that might not exist (not sure why you do), then you're right...just check to see if the node key exists in the list to decide if a child is empty instead of me checking for 0.  It sounds like you're on the right track, and my sample should show you the mechanics of walking your tree to any depth.  Why don't you post your code if you still need help

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve! Your code helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses your data structure and produces paths to each leaf node.  To make it interesting, I chose to have the path consist of the names of the nodes.  The path could just as easily be the node numbers.  I'm not sure why a child node would have a number and yet not exist, so my example assumes that if a child node entry is non-zero, then the node exists:

```
from pprint import pprint

btree = {
    1: ["Node 1", 2, 3],
    2: ["Node 2", 4, 0],
    3: ["Node 3", 0, 0],
    4: ["Node 4", 5, 0],
    5: ["Node 5", 6, 0],
    6: ["Node 6", 7, 0],
    7: ["Node 7", 0, 0],
}

def do_node(id, path, result):
    node = btree[id]
    if node[1] == 0 and node[2] == 0:
        # This node has no children, and is thus a leaf node, so add it to the result list
        result.append(path + [node[0]])
    else:
        # This is a non-leaf node, so process its children
        if node[1] != 0:
            do_node(node[1], path + [node[0]], result)
        if node[2] != 0:
            do_node(node[2], path + [node[0]], result)


def print_leaf_paths(tree):
    result = []
    do_node(1, [], result)
    pprint(result)

print_leaf_paths(btree)
```

The sample tree has two leaf nodes, one right away and one down 5 levels.  The result is:

```
[['Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6', 'Node 7'],
 ['Node 1', 'Node 3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses your data structure and produces paths to each leaf node.  To make it interesting, I chose to have the path consist of the names of the nodes.  The path could just as easily be the node numbers.  I'm not sure why a child node would have a number and yet not exist, so my example assumes that if a child node entry is non-zero, then the node exists:

```
from pprint import pprint

btree = {
    1: ["Node 1", 2, 3],
    2: ["Node 2", 4, 0],
    3: ["Node 3", 0, 0],
    4: ["Node 4", 5, 0],
    5: ["Node 5", 6, 0],
    6: ["Node 6", 7, 0],
    7: ["Node 7", 0, 0],
}

# Process a single node in a binary tree
def do_node(id, path, result):
    node = btree[id]
    if node[1] == 0 and node[2] == 0:
        # No children, so this is a leaf node.  Add it to the result list
        result.append(path + [node[0]])
    else:
        # Non-leaf node, so process the node's children recursively.
        if node[1] != 0:
            do_node(node[1], path + [node[0]], result)
        if node[2] != 0:
            do_node(node[2], path + [node[0]], result)


# Build a list of "paths" to each of the leaf nodes in a binary tree
def print_leaf_paths(tree):
    result = []
    do_node(1, [], result)
    pprint(result)

print_leaf_paths(btree)
```

The sample tree has two leaf nodes, one right below the root and one down 5 levels.  The result is:

```
[['Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6', 'Node 7'],
 ['Node 1', 'Node 3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
tree = {1: ['Node 1', 2, 3], 2: ['Node 2', 4, 0], 3: ['Node 3', 0, 0], 4: ['Node 4', 5, 0], 5: ['Node 5', 6, 0], 6: ['Node 6', 7, 0], 7: ['Node 7', 0, 0]}
def paths(a, c = []):
  if a not in tree:
    yield tuple(c)
  else:
    for i in tree[a][1:]:
      yield from paths(i, c+[tree[a][0]])

print(list(set(paths(1))))
```

Output:

```
[('Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6'), ('Node 1', 'Node 2'), ('Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4'), ('Node 1', 'Node 3'), ('Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4', 'Node 5'), ('Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 4', 'Node 5', 'Node 6', 'Node 7')]
```